# Which recommendation engine can be used for a django site with a postgresql db?

Tags: django, postgresql, recommendation-engine

It is for a media site with videos of different genres (quite similar to hulu content) built on Django with a PostgreSQL database backend.

Comment: Roughly how many daily users are there and how often do they watch videos?

Comment: I am expecting initially around 5000 views a day on the site. But this will definitely increase